# Dozer + Spring: MappingException: Dozer Bean Mapper is already initialized

Tags: java, spring, dozer

I am trying to implement Dozer as help for bridge pattern on my current webapp running Spring and Hibernate but I think I am doing something wrong, since trying to use a DozerBeanMapper instance more than once, will give me a MappingException.

Spring config:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    ...
    @Bean
    public DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper() {
        return new DozerBeanMapper();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Service
public class FooService {
    @Autowired
    private DozerBeanMapper mapper;

    public void doSomething() {
        mapper.addMapping(new CustomRules());
        mapper.map(foo, ImmutableFoo.class);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

First time I call this service will work fine, but any further attempt to use it will result in an exception on `mapper.addMapping()`. Can someone please point what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should not add mapper every time you call `doSomething`, even if it would worked it would be less scalable. In this case you should move `mapper.addMapping(new Custom Rules());` to bean instantiation.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  ...
    @Bean
    public DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper() {
        DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        mapper.addMapping(new CustomRules());
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

You have to make all your configuration to dozer before using it - `mapper.map(...)`. After first dozer usage, dozer sets its internal property to not allow to add mapping or other reconfiguration.